# ¿Como funciona este código?

Tags: r

Estoy trabajando en R y quiero comparar si una tabla que cree anteriormente siendo llenada con números aleatorios tiene 2 o mas números repetidos.

```
    fechas <- floor(runif(N)*365)+1 # Se asigna una fecha de nacimiento a cada persona
    
    # Creamos una tabla con las fechas
    tabla<-table(fechas)
    # Verificamos si se repiten
    resul<-tabla[tabla>1]
```

No entiendo la parte que se realiza la verificación, como funciona esa sintaxis, me gustaría tener una explicación

Answer (score 0):

El código para verificar valores repetidos en ese ejemplo realiza un contaje de los valores pasados a la tabla. Si alguno de los valores se repite, el valor para el contaje será mayor a uno y R imprimirá los nombres y valores correspondientes en caso que exista alguno.

Un ejemplo sobre extracción de valores en una tabla puede ayudar a entender la sintaxis.

## Construyendo una tabla

```
data(iris)

tab <- table(iris$Petal.Length)
```

## Verificando atributos de la tabla

La función `table` crea una tabla de contajes con un vector
numérico de tipo "integer" y un atributo de tipo "character" que representa los nombres que corresponden con cada valor en la tabla de contajes

```
str(tab)
 'table' int [1:43(1d)] 1 1 2 7 13 13 7 4 2 1 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  ..$ : chr [1:43] "1" "1.1" "1.2" "1.3" ...
```

Los atributos de la tabla pueden ser verificados con el siguiente código

```
attributes(tab)
```

## Extrayendo valores

Para acceder a cada elemento de la tabla puede ser usado el operador `[` que permite extraer valores de un vector

El siguiente código  extrae el segundo valor ("1") de la tabla con su respectivo nombre ("1.1")

```
tab[2]# 
1.1 
  1
```

Este código extrae los primeros 5 valores de la tabla:

```
tab[1:5]   1 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 
  1   1  2   7  13
```

El vector de enteros ("integer") permite la extracción de valores usando operadores lógicos, lo que facilita extraer valores mayores o menores a un número específico usando el operador `>` o `<` respectivamente:

```
tab[tab >7]
1.4 1.5 4.5 5.1 
 13  13   8   8
```